# speech recognition doesn't work in chrome on iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using standard JS speech recognition in my NextJS 13 app, and it works well in Chrome web browser and on Android. But it doesn't work when I try to run it in Chrome on iOS, but in Safari it works well. What can be the issue? I checked Chrome settings and access to mic is allowed there.

This is the speech recognition method that I use:

```
// new speech recognition object
var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
            
// This runs when the speech recognition service starts
recognition.onstart = function() {
    console.log("We are listening. Try speaking into the microphone.");
};

recognition.onspeechend = function() {
    // when user is done speaking
    recognition.stop();
}
              
// This runs when the speech recognition service returns result
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    var transcript = event.results[0][0].transcript;
};
              
// start recognition
recognition.start();
```

Comment: Make sure that you have granted the necessary permissions for the website to access your microphone. You can check this by going to Settings > Privacy > Microphone on your iOS device.

Comment: yes, I checked in Settings > Privacy > Microphone, it has access to mic.